# Don't bundle process.env variables, webpack/vue.js

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack

I have a Vue.js application that imports private npm packages that are Vue.js libraries:

```
// Vue.js app
import { someComponent } from '@private-npm/some-library';
```

The `someComponent` has some code that looks as such:

```
// someComponent
const username = process.env.USERNAME;
```

When I build `some-library`, so that I can publish it to my private repo, it writes the process environment variables in plain text inside the bundle file.

So my concerns:

- Even though my npm is private, I feels like bad practice to have my environment variables written to the module which someone can install and view inside `node_modules`.
- I need to be able to build the Vue.js app that uses the library with different environment variables

So, in summary, I need my bundled library to not import the real value of the process environment variable and instead leave it as `process.env.USERNAME` so when the Vue.js app builds it can dynamically change that variable via a `.env`.

Comment: I think you could maybe make that variable a function that returns `process.env.USERNAME` instead.

Comment: It seems your private package must be built before it can be used, which means the username will be injected into the built code (because that is part of the build process); if you don't want this to happen then you cannot built it ahead of time and instead build on a per-use basis alongside your main app. The private package was not designed to have the username dynamically set.